# Intent is not working at Onboarding Screen

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I tried cleaning up and rebuild the project but none of them worked

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentpage+1);

        if (mCurrentpage == mDots.length-1) {
            Intent login = new Intent(OnBoardingActivity.this,LoginActivity.class); //*showing unable to find class LoginActivity*
            startActivity(login);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".OnBoardingActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Do you import LoginActivity into OnboardingAtivity and register it in Manifest file as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file which is `LoginActivity`.

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
```

Add this under `OnBoardingActivity` in your manifest like the following.

```
<activity android:name=".OnBoardingActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to LoginActivity extends with AppCompatActivity. And also declare in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {}
```

And add in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code and your manifest file. It is clear that you didn't add LoginActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml file
You need to add LoginActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml like this below code.

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
```

Full source code of the following manifest will be looked like this below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="">

 <application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
  <activity android:name=".OnBoardingActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
 </application>
</manifest>
```